# Is the set of probability distributions on $R^n$ with compact support sequence compact

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request

Let $D$ be a set of probability distributions on some compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is the set $D$ sequentially compact in weak-topology? 
I am fairly certain that the answer is. Is there a good reference that where can look this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  The main tool is [Prokhorov's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem). Because your probability measures are all supported on the same compact set, they are automatically uniformly tight. A standard textbook is Billingsley's *Convergence of Probability Measures*; a sterner treatment is Parthasarathy, *Probability Measures on Metric Spaces*.

Comment: But shouldn't the space of distributions (over D) also be compact wrt - not only the Prokhorov metric but - L1 metric? Because by Skorokhod's representation theorem - every sequence (of distributions) has a convergent subsequence means this subsequence (as good as) converges a.s. and hence in L1.

Comment: @Canine360  I'm not sure I know what you mean by the L1 metric on the set of probability distributions over $D$.  Do you mean the total variation distance? Or the ordinary L1 distance restricted to prob. distributions with density functions?  Give a formula, please.

Comment: Yes I mean the ordinary $L1$ distance restricted to probability distributions. If $X_n \Rightarrow X$, by the repr thm, $Y_n \rightarrow Y\;a.s.$, $Y_n \sim X_n$ and $Y \sim X$ in distr. By compactness ($\therefore$ Dominated convergence theorem), $E|X_n-X| \Rightarrow 0$. So every sequence (of distributions) has a convergent subsequence, in the metric space $(D,L_1)$.  

Is that correct?

Comment: @Canine360  I doubt it: the unit ball in $L^1([0,1])$  is not compact.  Post it as a separate question, with proper definitions of what you mean, rather than in comments.